# Is inverted word order such as "Anybody else does have any other concerns?" correct?

Tags: word-order

I know that if I was supposed to spin a grammatically correct sentence with the same meaning, I would probably say:

> Does anybody else have any other concerns?

However, is the sentence in the subject of the question correct as well, even if unusual??

Comment: And you would probably be right!

Comment: The sentence in the subject is not overly grammatically _incorrect_ as such, but it is not a question. It is a kind of equivalent of, “I _do_ have other concerns”, i.e., an emphatic statement. The thing that makes it grammatically _dubious_ is the fact that pronouns/determiners that begin with ‘any’ are not used in positive statements, but only in questions and negated statements. Instead, you would have to say, “Somebody else does have (some) other concerns”.

Comment: Would the “does” really be used? “Anybode else want some coffee?”

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: The *Does ...* is implied (and elided) in that construction.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for the comment. However, assume this was intended to be a question. Then usage of "Anybody" would be justified?

Comment: If it is intended to be a question, then the use of *anybody* is correct - and your second version beginning "Does ..." is fine. But as JBJ said in his first comment "The sentence in the subject ... is *not a question*." - the word order is wrong. If I were reading / hearing the sentence in the subject line, I would not know whether you were asking a question or making a statement, because the word order suggests a statement, but the use of *anybody* suggests a question.

Comment: @TrevorD I think your comment qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anybody else does have any other concerns?

To my mind it is not clear whether this sentence is a statement or a question:

- If it's intended to be a statement, then the use of "Anybody" is incorrect, because that implies a question, so it should be something like:

  > Somebody else does have (some) other concerns
  >   I do have other concerns
- If, on the other hand, it is intended to be a question, then the use of "anybody" is correct, but the *subject-verb word order* is wrong for a question and should be reversed. Hence your alternative version is fine:

  > Does anybody else have any other concerns?

Summarising, if I were reading / hearing the sentence:

> Anybody else does have any other concerns?

I would not know whether you were asking a question or making a statement, because the word order suggests a statement, but the use of "anybody" suggests a question.

Comment: english.stackexchange.com/questions/112766/… has already addressed the (agreed correct) device of using non-inverted sentences as questions. 'John is in prison?' Such a sentence is marked as a question by intonation in speech and by a question mark in print. However, structures involving auxiliaries are a little trickier when combined with pronouns/determiners that begin with ‘any’  (though the do-elision recommended by Carsten works).